# Laravel 5 route defaults to https

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I do this

`<li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>`

The output is:

`<li><a href="https://example.com/">Home</a></li>`

But I want:

`<li><a href="http://example.com/">Home</a></li>`

I don't know how to fix this problem. In my config/app.php is already set to

`'url' => 'http://example.com'`

Comment: Why are you doing a login via `http`? There is no excuse in 2015 to login via `http` anymore. Just login via `https`.

Comment: That is just an example. Even if I want to point to any other page, it shows `https`

Comment: So is part of your whole site `https` and part `http`? Just make it all `https` - there is no need to have `http` anymore...?

Comment: The issue is not if the site is http or https. I want http urls and how to make it happen. All urls are https now, when i want all urls as http.

Comment: How did you define your route? By default there is no route named login.

Comment: Because you probably are on a `https` url already - Laravel then assumes your whole site is `https` - since in 2015 there is no reason to switch back to `http`. So when you create a link from that page - it is assuming it is `https`.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the question so it is much clear now. I am not on `https`, I am on `http`, but url again starts with `http` even I don't use `route(...)` and I am using `url(..)`

Comment: Issue is even a normal link like <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}"> goes to https://example.com not http://example.com

Comment: This method builds url for (`url('/')`) - https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bf87be23a152895ea6869f50aaaee25aac7870ac/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L144 . As you can see, it invokes another method - `getScheme` - to determine the current schema. And `getScheme` can return `https` only if current request is `https`, or scheme is forced, or the `$secure` argument is true. So,maybe it is some place in your code, where you force the scheme to `https`? https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bf87be23a152895ea6869f50aaaee25aac7870ac/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L228

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov Hi, If possible please check this: http://stepuphyd.com/ There is a link FOO/BAR and I have used `<a href=" {{ url('foo/bar', $parameters = [], $secure = null) }}">FOO/BAR</a>` to generate the link, it is https but domain is not https

Comment: If I want to use forceSchema method of URLGenarator.. Where should i use?

Comment: I don't know the problem, but I have done this in my controller `app('url')->forceSchema('http');`

Comment: Very intresting, may be there is some modules which forces the schema?